# Anonymous access to web site default doc

Tags: authentication, iis, url-rewriting

We have a web site in IIS 7, that has a default document (index.asp) set. The entire site uses basic authentication except the index.asp page. This is working correctly if I enter the domain with the actual page name ([www.mysite.com/index.asp](http://www.mysite.com/index.asp)). However, without the page name ([www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)) I am prompted for credentials, even though it is the same page.

I've tried various web config changes and tried it with anonymous user set to the app pool and the IUSR account and it doesn't work either way. I'm thinking maybe I need to enable and then configure URL rewriting for this site but I'm not positive.

If you need any other info let me know.

thanks!

Comment: What is your web.config like? In addition to basic authentication, have you enabled anonymous authentication?

Comment: Anonymous is enabled but only for that page. And it works just fine when I navigate directly to that page, but when I end up at it as the default, without the page name in the url, it doesn't work. It's a classic asp page so there isn't a web config file.

Comment: As long as you configure basic authentication for the site, IIS will automatically generate web.config for you even if there is only one index.asp file in the site.